# how to create 4096 aligned table[x][4096]

Tags: c++, c, winapi, optimization, memory-alignment

I want to get a table of [x][4096] (for example int table[4096][4096])
but I am not sure how to do it - especially in more generel way (it is
on many compilers also the older ones (mingw, dmc, lcc, b55)

I want to get table witch each row fills into one (or multyply) system 
page (for efficiency, will it be faster? as far as i know it could)
so I want to get ann array which fills up a set of system pages and it
is much aligned to them

(I want no mislaligments, no empty spaces in pages)

1) could I get static array in this way (in many compilers)
2) how it could it be done in malloc way? (I remember vaguely that malloc
can put some metadata before ram he allocs so it would spoil the image, 
maybe it is also not allocing precise amount of bytes (?) but I am not sure
to that

Can I gat such clear alloc - for example 256 aligned 4K pages as a table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can over allocate and fine tune the pointer:

```
 int *a = malloc(4096*4096*4+4095);
 int *b = (int*) (((int)a)+4095 & (~4095)));
```

It's also possible (but not guaranteed) that one allocates e.g. 64 + 64 bytes, finds that the addresses are 80 bytes apart and then calculates the length of next allocation unit L to make the large unit to align to given address.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int *a = malloc(64);
  int *b = malloc(64);
  long long excess = ((long)b - (long)a)-64;
  int *c = malloc(4096 - (((int)(b) & 4095) + excess*2 + 64));
  int *d = malloc(4096*4);
  printf("%x %x %x %x\n",
     (int)a & 0xffffffff,(int)b & 0xffffffff, 
     (int)c & 0xffffffff,(int)d & 0xffffffff);
}
```

Output: `18e2010 18e2060 18e20b0 18e3000`

One notice though: the last malloc for d=malloc(4096*4096) **failed** (and produced 0x55505010), because glib implementation allocates different size units from different pools or with different methods (eg. system call *kmalloc*). The first allocated address of every run seems to be biased by exactly 10(hex) bytes, because that's the space required by the bookkeeping and apparently the heap is already aligned by the system to 4096 byte boundary.

Comment: The first example you wrote seem to be reasonable way (You sure it will work?) How about static tables, do you know a way of static aligning that (at least on some compiler(s) if not all??) There is Alignas_ operator or something like that in new standards, will it work?

Comment: I'm sure that the first one works to align the pointer to 4096 byte boundary. But it's not guaranteed, that it will align to page boundaries in some exotic OS (or with segmented architectures DOS+8086).

Comment: I found it as a partial answer (not about ststic only dynamic) but the routine you wrote is nice, i thing i will write aligned_malloc() on that so tnx for that :)

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen masking the lower bits to get the aligned address will work but you'll have a memory leak here once you free `a`. You need to store the original pointer somewhere and pass it to `free`. Your second  example I don't understand, I tried to execute it and haven't received anything aligned: http://ideone.com/Kv9XSx

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen I was referring to the problems in your solution, not to the correct parts. In your first example you destroy the original pointer given to you by the OS and you have no way to retrieve it for freeing. Your second example simply not working.

Comment: Your last edit is still not good enough. The solution isn't user-friendly, as the user will have to manage 2 pointers, while he needs only one.

Answer (score 2):

The page allocation function in Windows is `VirtualAlloc`. Pass both `MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE` to get an actual allocation, not just a reservation.

Answer (score 1):

Since question is tagged winapi, I assume you are using Windows.
In that case, you probaly want to simply use [`_aligned_malloc()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z34s9c6%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

On Linux/POSIX systems, there is [`posix_memalign()`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/posix_memalign.3.html).

Using one of these API's, you should allocate big memory block which will be aligned to 4KB. Then you simply should access it using normal pointers.

Comment: are you sure that it will give for example one page, and do not touches the other ones?

Comment: I cannot tell what exactly Microsoft promised here. But you can test it by checking if returned address is divisible by 4096

Comment: how about static tables (especially two dimensional t[100][4096] ? can I make it fit perfectly into pages?)

Answer (score 1):

You can do the alignment you ask for but it won't be portable since there is no standard instructions in `C/C++` for alignment definition.

For static data it's usually some `#pragma` or compiler intrinsics.

E.g., in VC++ there is a `__declspec( align( # ) )` that can be used for data alignment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83ythb65(v=vs.110).aspx

For dynamic data it's the same non-portable solution, see @mvp answer for details. However, for dynamic data you can implement your own aligned-data allocator, based on the standard `malloc` function. Since it's based on standard library, **your allocator will be portable**.

Comment: how? by allocating more and up-align that?

Comment: Yes. It's actually a common interview question